# Dart CSS3 Transitions white glow not wanted

Tags: html, css, dart

So I started to learn just yet so I am a beginner. 
What I want to achieve is changing divs with different backgrounds like [here](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/#cfimg7) . In the tutorial is accomplished with  but I want to do it with background properity because I dont want my images to be draggable.

What happens is that instead of each image flowing to each other and changing colors, I get some white glow that happens. Any help?

Here is Html

```
<p id="transitionControls">
  <span>Snap1</span>
  <span>Snap2</span>
  <span>Snap3</span>
  <span>Snap4</span>
  <span>Snap5</span>
  <span>Snap6</span>
  <span>Snap7</span>
</p>  

<div id="imageContainer" class='opaque'>
  <div id="Snap7"  class="snap"></div>
  <div id="Snap6"  class="snap"></div>
  <div id="Snap5"  class="snap"></div>
  <div id="Snap4"  class="snap"></div>
  <div id="Snap3"  class="snap"></div>
  <div id="Snap2"  class="snap"></div>
  <div id="Snap1"  class="snap"></div>
  </div>
```

Here is CSS:

```
div{
  position:absolute;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin:auto;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}

div.snap {
  opacity:0;
}

div.opaque{
  opacity:1;
  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=1);
 }
```

Where each Snap has simple CSS

```
#Snap1 {
background: url('img/Snap_1.jpg') no-repeat;
width: 1680px;
height: 1350px;
}
```

Here is dart script

```
import 'dart:html';

DivElement div;
var counter = 0;

void main() {
  query("#transitionControls")
    ..onClick.listen(changeDiv);
}
//
void changeDiv(MouseEvent event) {


  SpanElement snap = event.target;
  var text = snap.text;
  div = query(".opaque");


  query("#$text").classes.add("opaque");

  div.classes.remove("opaque");
  }
```

Comment: FYI, if you don't want the image to be draggable, you can also listen to drag start event and cancel the default action `query('#img').onDragStart.listen((e) => e.preventDefault());`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I like it

Comment: Still having the same issue, anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some repositioned CSS properties here and there. Some Dart code refactoring here and there. Adding the `#imageContainer` block element under an `opaque` class might block what you aim to do. Your example would look like this:

For the DOM:

```html
<p id="transitionControls">
  <span>Snap1</span>
  <span>Snap2</span>
  <span>Snap3</span>
</p>

<div id="imageContainer">
  <div id="Snap1" class="opaque"></div>
  <div id="Snap2" class="snap"></div>
  <div id="Snap3" class="snap"></div>
</div>
```

For the CSS:

```css
  #imageContainer {
    position: relative;
    height: 24rem;
    background-color: #ddd;
    margin: auto;
  }

  #imageContainer .snap,
  #imageContainer .opaque {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  }

  .snap {
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  }

  .opaque {
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=1);
  }

  #Snap1 {
    background-color: green;
  }

  #Snap2 {
    background-color: blue;
  }

  #Snap3 {
    background-color: red;
  }
```

The Dart is pretty ugly, could be refactored.

```dart
import 'dart:html';

final triggers = query('#transitionControls');

main() {
  triggers.onClick.listen(changeDiv);
}

changeDiv(Event event) {
  SpanElement snap = event.target;

  // Fade the current opaque layer.
  query('#imageContainer .opaque').classes
      ..remove('opaque')
      ..add('snap');

  // Reveal the target layer.
  query('#${snap.text}').classes
      ..remove('snap')
      ..add('opaque');
}
```

Hope this helps.